# How to send a data back from a Service into Activity?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-service

I have created a simple service and passed the BMI calculated from activity into service. In service on based of BMI value I have find out if its healthy , over weight  or under weight. And now I wish to return back that string to Main activity. Tried to create a broadcast in service ,but wasn't able to understand how to receive that broadcast in main activity. Any help would be highly appreciated.

My main Activity

> public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

> ```
> @Override
> protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
>     btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
>
>     height = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.height);
>     weight = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.weight);
> ```

> ```
>     btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
>         @Override
>         public void onClick(View v) {
>             Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,second.class);
>
>             String str1 = weight.getText().toString();
>             String str2 = height.getText().toString();
>             float weight = Float.parseFloat(str1);
>             float height = Float.parseFloat(str2)/100;
>             float bmiValue = calculateBMI(weight, height);
>             intent.putExtra("number1",bmiValue);
>             startActivityForResult(intent,1);
> ```

// sending BMI value from activity to service

> ```
>             Intent intent2 = new Intent(MainActivity.this,MyService.class);
>             Bundle extras = new Bundle();
>             extras.putFloat("key", bmiValue);
>             intent2.putExtras(extras);
>
>             startService(intent2);
>
>
>
>         }
>     });
>
> }
>
>
> //Calculate BMI
> private float calculateBMI (float weight, float height) {
>     return (float) (weight / (height * height));
> }
> }
> ```

//inside service

> public class MyService extends Service {
> @Nullable
> @Override
> public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
> return null;
> }
>
> ```
> @Override
> public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
>        // receiving BMI Value from service 
>         Float BMI;
>         Bundle b=intent.getExtras();
>         BMI = b.getFloat("key",0);
>         Log.d("testone", String.valueOf(BMI));
>      // sending string as a broadcast
> ```

> 

```
        Intent sendLevel = new Intent();
>             sendLevel.setAction("sending data");
>             sendLevel.putExtra( "DATA",Bmi(BMI));
>              LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(sendLevel);
>             //sendBroadcast(sendLevel);
> 
>         return START_STICKY`;
```

> ```
> }
>
> @Override
> public void onDestroy() {
>     super.onDestroy();
> }
>
>
> public String Bmi(float bmi){
>  String type;
>     if(bmi<=18.5) {
>         type = "under weight";
>     }   else if(bmi<=35){type="healthy";}
>     else{
>         type="obese";
>     }
>     return type;
> } }
> ```

Comment: You must bind to your service and use messenger. There is a good example. You could use Aidl, but messenger is simple to understand.

Comment: can you please give a code example

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services. Good exemple here.

Comment: Here's an example that does exactly what you want: https://www.truiton.com/2014/09/android-service-broadcastreceiver-example/

Comment: Bound Services would be an option, but isn't necessary. Using bound services is more complicated.

Comment: You need use a foreground service and send bmi to activity by a BroadcastReceiver